# Disable generation of crash logs in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to prevent an iOS application from generating crash logs? I have tried searching for relevant ways and options, but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: No, it isn't. Why would you want that in that first place?

Comment: My application just went through penetration testing, and the requirement is now to stop crash logs from being generated. I am totally left confused..!!

Comment: Maybe the correct action for this requirement is to fix the bugs in your app that cause your app to crash?

Comment: Why is somebody specifying that as a requirement?

Comment: That's a really weird way of saying "fix the bugs that cause a crash"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It's very simple: Avoid bugs that crash your application. You can avoid these bugs by analysing crash logs and figuring out what caused those crashes.